Find unknown sample characteristics
How can I translate score values from an unknown sample into known variables after performing a transformation model similar to PCA?
I have analyzed four known samples (with two variables, A and P, per sample) using a spectroscopic method. After applying a transformation model (similar to PCA), I obtained score values (Score_X and Score_Y), which I have plotted using ggplot2. For the known samples, A and P values are available. Is there a method to translate the score values of an unknown sample back into the corresponding A and P variables?
The code is provided below:
# Load the necessary scales package
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)


df <- structure(list(Sample = structure(1:5, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "Test"), class = "factor"),
                     Score_X = c(-0.465, 0.7984, 0.0867, -0.3400, 0.0065), 
                     Score_Y = c(0.4823, 0.009, 0.62567, -0.476, -0.2491)), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

Sample_Label <- c("A\nP% = 20.0%\nA% = 3.4%", 
                  "B\nP% = 27.0%\nA% = 2.0%", 
                  "L\nP% = 20.0%\nA% = 2.0%", 
                  "M\nP% = 27.0%\nA% = 3.4%", 
                  "Test")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Score_X, y = Score_Y, color = Sample)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.2, show.legend = F) +
  geom_mark_circle(aes(fill = Sample), alpha = 0.2, show.legend = F) +     
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_text(data = df, aes(x = Score_X, y = Score_Y, label = Sample_Label, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.5), size = 4, nudge_x = -0.1, fontface = "bold", show.legend = F) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),  
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),                  
        legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),            
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10) 
  ) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-0.6, 1), breaks = seq(-0.6, 1, by = 0.1), labels = label_number()) +  
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.6, 1), breaks = seq(-0.6, 1, by = 0.1), labels = label_number()) +  
  scale_color_discrete(name = "") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "")

